# How to fix the incompatibility issue for Vertx-core 4.5.4 version with smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging

In my project, which was developed by using Quarkus 3.2.9.Final version, in that we are producing and consuming Kafka messages using Smallrye reactive messaging.
In this Quarkus version it has preloaded "io.vertx:vertx-core" 4.4.6 version jar is there, which is vulnerable. So I am upgrading this to the latest non-vulnerable version (Vertx-core 4.5.4).

But while upgrading this to latest version, our application is not getting started due to the below exception while Quarkus class loading.

```
2024-03-11T06:06:27,338Z ERROR traceId=,spanId=, className= [io.quarkus.runtime.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at com.fiserv.emp.audit.Main.main(Main.java:14)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io/vertx/core/impl/VertxInternal.createEventLoopContext()Lio/vertx/core/impl/EventLoopContext; (loaded from file:/C:/Users/FC346TN/.m2/repository/io/vertx/vertx-core/4.5.4/vertx-core-4.5.4.jar by QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader: DEV@1c48251e) called from class io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.KafkaSource (loaded from file:/C:/Users/FC346TN/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/reactive/smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka/4.6.0/smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka-4.6.0.jar by QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader: DEV@1c48251e).**
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.impl.KafkaSource.<init>(KafkaSource.java:107)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector.getPublisher(KafkaConnector.java:211)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector_Subclass.getPublisher$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector_Subclass$$function$$9.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext$NextAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:97)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.devmode.DevModeSupportConnectorFactoryInterceptor.intercept(DevModeSupportConnectorFactoryInterceptor.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.devmode.DevModeSupportConnectorFactoryInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.DuplicatedContextConnectorFactoryInterceptor.intercept(DuplicatedContextConnectorFactoryInterceptor.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.DuplicatedContextConnectorFactoryInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector_Subclass.getPublisher(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector_ClientProxy.getPublisher(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.createPublisher(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:172)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.register(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:134)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.initialize(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:106)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory_ClientProxy.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.MediatorManager$$Lambda$1211/0x0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.MediatorManager.start(MediatorManager.java:212)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.extension.MediatorManager_ClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.onApplicationStart(SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.java:52)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle_Observer_onApplicationStart_68e7b57eb97cb75d597c5b816682366e888d0d9b.notify(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:346)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:155)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:106)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

Looks in this latest Vertx-core 4.5.4 jar "EventLoopContext" class was removed, but the smallrye reactive messaging kafka 4.6.0 version is expecting this class to be loaded while startup.

So i had tried to upgrade the "io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka" jar to above 4.6.0 version till its latest version (4.18.0 as of now), but none of the smallrye reactive messaging kafka is compatible with Vertx-core 4.5.4 version.

So please help on with your suggestion to find the compatible version of smallrye reactive messaging for Vertx-core 4.5.4 version